# Did any saint pray '15 Prayers of Saint Bridget of Sweden'?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, saint, devotion

Was there any saint (or blessed, or venerable) that prayed '15 Prayers of Saint Bridget of Sweden'? Does any saint (or blessed, or venerable) recommend that prayer? Did the St. Bridget pray them?

Comment: Good question and a hard one to answer!